# All virtual hosts giving same site

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu

My linux server hosts 3 virtual hosts, example.com, example.net, and example.org, separately configured to listen on 192.168.1.90:80 and respond to the addresses, the root directories are different and configured well.
But which ever site I try to access it always delivers example.com.

```
<VirtualHost lists.pirate-party.in:80>
DocumentRoot "/home/webmaster/www/PirateParty/wiki"
<Directory "/home/webmaster/www/PirateParty/wiki">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost www.pirate-party.in:80>
DocumentRoot "/home/webmaster/www/PirateParty"
<Directory "/home/webmaster/www/PirateParty">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Could you provide the configuration for your vhosts ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/nNLJyUPY

Comment: There might be a confusing in linking between sites-available and sites enabled directories. Could you possibly post the output of : ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-enabled ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-available

Comment: Why not put your config right here in the question?  You do want an answer don't you?

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `ServerName` directive. Please note the `NameVirtualHost` directive is mandatory, as mentioned by @Ladadadada.

(From Apache's documentation : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html)

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.tld
ServerAlias domain.tld *.domain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/domain
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.otherdomain.tld
DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Added and restarted. Still no change

Comment: What's the output of the restart command ?

Comment: You might want to mention that the [NameVirtualHost directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) is *required* for name-based virtual hosts rather than just putting it in the example config without mentioning it.

Comment: I edited my post ;)